# Выполнение StopMixMonitor() в диалплане не приводит к закрытию файла

Tags: asterisk

Кусочек диалплана:

`exten => incoming_extension,1,NoOp(Incoming call)
  same => n,Set(CHANNEL(hangup_handler_push)=subIncomingHangUpHandler,s,1())
  same => n,Queue(incoming_queue,tTr)
  same => n,HangUp()`

И саб который "готовит" файл записи:

`[subIncomingHangUpHandler]
exten => s,1,NoOp(This hangup sub exec after ending of incoming call)
 same => n,StopMixMonitor(${CHANNEL})
 same => n,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1/agi.php,${CDR(recordfile)})
 same => n,Return()`

Так вот после вызова StopMixMonitor() я ожидаю что произойдет следующее:

`== MixMonitor close filestream (mixed)
== Executing [/etc/asterisk/scripts/convertToMp3.sh record.wav]
== End MixMonitor Recording SIP/mts-rek-3-00000a76`

и я смогу спокойно работать с готовым mp3 файликом.
Однако на деле не происходит закрытия файла в рамках выполнения саба, и, соответственно, файл занят, да и не мп3 он на тот момент. А вышеуказанное действие выполняется только после "смерти" канала.

На данный момент использую вариант с копированием исходного wav файла, преобразованием его мп3 уже в аги скрипте, и дальнейшая работа с ним. Но этой очень кривой и костыльный способ.
Подскажите как можно закрыть файл в рамках жизни канала.

Версия Астериска 13.9.1

Answer (score 2):

[Ответ](https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-24345) на вопрос не столь очевиден. Он заключается в следующем - для того что бы закрыть файл, необходимо в качестве аргумента указывать id канала MixMonitor (не очевидно то, где брать этот id). Я наивно полагал что id канала равен ${CHANNEL}. Однако он хранится в переменной, которая заполняется при вызове MixMonitor с аргументом i(MIXMONITORIDVARIABLE). Т.е. `MixMonitor(fname,i(MIXMONITORIDVARIABLE))`. Далее уже совсем просто, в приложение StopMixMonitor в качестве аргумента необходимо передать ${MIXMONITORIDVARIABLE}, это действие закроет файл, и с ним уже можно будет что-нить вытворять.

Хочу обратить внимание что вышеописанное только закрывает файл, а конвертировать его необходимо уже отдельно, например через приложение System().
Надеюсь это поможет еще кому-нибудь.